# Pass array of objects between components with drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

[image: I want to achieve some thing like this]I want to drag and pass object element between 2 components, I did not found any materiel and package with this use case.
I have two components name **Assets** and **Listing**. In **Assets** component I have multiple lists, I can select multiple lists from **Assets** component and want to drag these selected lists and drop them in **Listing** component.

I don't know if this is possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: how are they dispklayed? i guess you can bind to the `ondrag` event of the source and destination eleents and define your code appropriately

Comment: I have added image of the problem, in question

Comment: Did you try `react-dnd`?

Comment: yes, there no use case that match my problem